# How should I pass a querystring through these wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, parameters, parameter-passing

I have tried a few recommendations from tutorials, but I have not been able to get them to work.  On my website, [huddlegram.com](http://huddlegram.com) (not a functional website, just working on frontend), a visitor can enter their email address in the front page.  Upon clicking signup, they will be directed to a signup page that passes the email string in the url.  I have three buttons using the siteorigin widget.  How can I get the string to pass to the next pages as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query string with `$_GET` in PHP. See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Example...
 On submission of form redirect to `https://huddlegram.com/page?email=test@test.com`. Where `test@test.com` is the users email.

On the next page you can get the query string and assign to PHP variable using `$_GET`.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
   $email = $_GET['email'];

//do what you want with email...

}
else {
    // No email
}
?>
```